# Comparing 2 values from the same line and looping to the next for all line in file

Tags: python, text, compare

main code:

```
fgcuWins = 0
fgcuLoses = 0
ties = 0
file = open("2022_sport.txt", "r")
for lines in file:
    if char[1] == char[3]:
        ties += 1
        lines += 1
    elif char[1] > char[3]:
        fgcuWins += 1
        lines += 1
    else:
        fgcuLoses += 1
        lines += 1

print(fgcuWins)
print(fgcuLoses)
print(ties)
```

contents of 2022_sport.txt:

```
1-2
1-3
4-1
1-3
1-0
0-5
1-0
0-2
3-1
3-0
5-1
3-0
2-1
0-0
3-1
2-0
1-0
3-2
1-1
```

Was trying to compare int in column 1 to int in column 3 for the number of lines in the file. I cannot figure out how to do so and calculate wins loses and ties

Comment: What is `char` in your code?

Comment: You never set `char`. that should be `lines[0]` and `lines[2]`, since indexes start at 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read each line of file, split line on '-', compare left int to right int and increment applicable win, loss, tie count.

```py
wins = 0
losses = 0
ties = 0

with open('2022_sport.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip().split('-')
        if line[0] > line[1]:
            wins += 1
        if line[0] < line[1]:
            losses += 1 
        if line[0] == line[1]:  
            ties += 1

print('wins: ' + str(wins))
print('losses: ' + str(losses))
print('ties: ' + str(ties))
```

Output:

```
wins: 12
losses: 5
ties: 2
```

Comment: Why did you choose to have `split_lines` and `lines`? You could have read the file: `for line in f:` and then `line = line.strip().split('-')` and not needed the second for loop.

Comment: Agree, much more efficient. Thank you.